# Examples of One dimensional fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves

A one dimensional field $K$ over a ground field $k$ contains $k[x]$ for $x \in K \setminus k$ such that it is a finitely generated $k[x]$-module.

The textbook I'm studying uses its geometric interpretation to motivate a study of Algebraic curve, but geometry aside for now, is it of any significance in Number theory or other fields? What are particular examples other than finite algebraic extensions of $k[x]$?

Comment: The number theoretic analogue of $k[x]$ is usually $\mathbb{Z}$, and then you're looking at the ring of integers in a number field; the hope would be to apply some geometric ideas to the study of these.

Comment: @Hoot A f.g. k[x] module is analogous to f.g. Z-modules (by similarity of the prime spectra of their base rings), so one dimensional rings are similar to ring of integers. But what's troubling is that it is a field. I should then think of it as a purely Algebraic curiosity and let geometry leads, right? Many thanks.